'data(for:delegate:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer in Ollama Swift dependencies
I am facing the problem that when I install the Ollama dependencies from GitHub link :https://github.com/mattt/ollama-swift?tab=readme-ov-file
In the file Client.swift in dependencies, it said that 'data(for:delegate:)' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer even my repository is at IOS 18.0
enter image description here
First time trying to do my project in swift so I'm not sure what is happening to this
I tried to reinstall the dependencies but its not working
I tried to distribute the dependencies to all the targets but still not working
I tried to switch to different IOS but also not working

How did you install the dependency? Via Swift package manager or via cocoa pods?  If you used cocoapods what is the minimum target version you have specified in your podfile? Are you sure that the minimum supported version for your project is iOS 18 (or at least iOS 15?)

I went straight to the "Add Packages Dependencies" and pasted the GitHub link to download the dependency. Yes I have already checked my minimum supported version for the project is still at IOS 18

You may have keep a place where you said your app déploiement version is lower than iOS 15.

I have checked all and make sure they are all at iOS 18

Looking at the package, Ollama seems to only support macOS 13+. The error message is likely a misleading one. The package is not meant for iOS.

You can probably fork the repo, add iOS support to the platforms. Looking at the repo, I think it's as simple as that. Then you can make a PR against the original repo . https://github.com/mattt/ollama-swift/blob/9507c1d4189f908c26e9e59e400e049dab7ace03/Package.swift#L9. Someone already did this to add visionsOS support.

@Jacob Thank you, It's worked for me now. I thought it supported for IOS initially but when I add IOS support to the platforms, it can build successfully. Thank you so much and I very appreciate for your help
